# How to Apply formula in empty cell and otherwise do nothing and move to next sheet

Tags: vba

I cannot figure out how to "do nothing" if the cell selected is not empty. Or, skip worksheet which cell is not emplty. All vlookup formula is being applied in each worksheet when I run my macro.
Appreciate any help to figure out. :)

My code is below:

```
    Range("D25").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
        If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) = True Then
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R6C4,'Libor Rate'!C[-4]:C[-3],2,0)"
        Else
        'do nothing
            
    End If
```

Next ws
End Sub

Comment: It seems like you keep checking A1, you should check ActiveCell, i.e. try to change this, IF IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) = True Then

Comment: @Bilal  You could post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you keep checking A1, you should check `ActiveCell` i.e. try to change with this.

```
IF IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) = True Then
```